# sales order grid custom column filter QLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column

Tags: magento-1.9, overrides

Here is the class to rewrite sales order grid adding email column, there is an error for filtering by this email column

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'email' in
>   'where clause', query was: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM
>   `sales_flat_order_grid` AS `main_table` WHERE (`email` LIKE
>   '%abcd@gmail.com%')

when filtering, no matter how it didn't join the table,

echo select will print

> "SELECT `main_table`.*, `ce`.`email` FROM `sales_flat_order_grid` AS
>   `main_table` LEFT JOIN `customer_entity` AS `ce` ON ce.entity_id =
>   main_table.customer_id"

it shows the collection is joined, but it prints the error message anyway, any one know what is the problem?

---

```
    <?php

    class Namespace_Sales_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid {

        protected function _prepareColumns()
        {

            parent::_prepareColumns();

            foreach ($this->getColumns() as $columns) {
                switch($columns->getId()){
                    case 'action':
                        $columns->setTotalsLabel('');
                        break;
                    case 'status':
                        $columns->setFilter('_sales/adminhtml_widget_grid_column_filter_multiselect');
                        $columns->setFilterConditionCallback(array($this, '_addFilterMultiselect'));
                        break;
                    case 'store_id':
                        $columns->setFilter('namespace_sales/adminhtml_widget_grid_column_filter_multiselect');
                        $columns->setFilterConditionCallback(array($this, '_addFilterMultiselect'));
                        break;
                }
            }

            $this->addColumnAfter(
                'email',
                array(
                    'header'   => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Email'),
                    'align'    => 'left',
                    'index'    => 'email',
                    'filter_condition_callback' => array($this, '_filterEmailConditionCallback')
                    //'filter_index'    => 'email',
                ),
                'shipping_name'
            );

            $this->sortColumnsByOrder();

            return $this;
        }

        protected function _filterEmailConditionCallback($collection, $column)
        {

            $select = $collection->getSelect();

            if ($collection) {

                $field = ($column->getFilterIndex()) ? $column->getFilterIndex() : $column->getIndex();

                if ($column->getFilterConditionCallback()) {

                    $select = $collection->getSelect();
                    $cond = $column->getFilter()->getCondition();
                    echo $select;
//die();
                    $collection->addFieldToFilter('email', $cond);


                } else {

                    $cond = $column->getFilter()->getCondition();

                    if ($field && isset($cond)) {
                        $collection->addFieldToFilter($field, $cond);
                    }

                }
            }


            //return $this;
        }   

        protected function _prepareCollection()
        {

            $collection = Mage::getResourceModel(parent::_getCollectionClass());
            $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(array('ce' => 'customer_entity'),'ce.entity_id = main_table.customer_id', array('email'));
            $this->setCollection($collection);

            return Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid::_prepareCollection();
        }   

        protected function _prepareMassactionColumn(){

            parent::_prepareMassactionColumn();
            $this->_columns['massaction']->setTotalsLabel($this->__('Totals'));
            return $this;
        }

        public function getCountTotals()
        {
            return $this->getCollection()->count()>0;
        }

        public function getTotals()
        {

            $result = array();

            if($this->getCollection()->count()>0){
                $fields = array(
                    'base_grand_total' => array(), //actual column index, see _prepareColumns()
                    'grand_total' => array(),
                );

                $baseCurrencyCode = Mage::app()->getStore()->getBaseCurrencyCode(); 

                foreach ($this->getCollection() as $item) {
                    foreach($fields as $field=>$value){
                        $codeCurrency = $item->getOrderCurrencyCode();
                        if(strpos($field, 'base') !== false) {
                            $codeCurrency = $baseCurrencyCode;
                        }

                        if(!isset($fields[$field][$codeCurrency])){
                            $fields[$field][$codeCurrency] = 0;
                        }

                        //Base prices don't include currency. Must be converted in the current currency
                        if(strpos($field, 'base') !== false){
                            $total = Mage::helper('directory')->currencyConvert($item->getData($field), $baseCurrencyCode, $codeCurrency);
                        }
                        else {
                            $total = $item->getData($field);
                        }
                        $fields[$field][$codeCurrency]+=$total;
                   }
                }

                foreach ($fields as $field => $currencies) {
                    foreach ($currencies as $codeCurrency => $total) {
                        $result[$field][] = Mage::app()->getLocale()->currency($codeCurrency)->toCurrency($total);
                    }
                    $result[$field] = implode('<br />',$result[$field]);
                }
            }

            return new Varien_Object($result);
        }

        protected function _addFilterMultiselect($collection,$column)
        {

            if (($column->getId() == 'store_id' || $column->getId() == 'status') && $column->getFilter()->getValue()) {
                $_inNin = explode(',', $column->getFilter()->getValue());
                $inNin = array('in');

                foreach ($_inNin as $k => $v) {
                    if (is_string($v) && strlen(trim($v))) {
                        $inNin[] = trim($v);
                    }
                }

                if (count($inNin)>1 && in_array($inNin[0], array('in', 'nin'))) {
                    $in = $inNin[0];
                    $values = array_slice($inNin, 1);
                    $collection->addFieldToFilter('main_table.'.$column->getId(), array($in => $values));
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: $this->addColumnAfter( 'email' ...

Your problem seems to be coming from here, is this attempted to select from the database with the email column on that table that does not possess it?

Comment: the collection is skipping the join query

Comment: And the email address is only on the table it's joining (customer_entity) not on the one it is currently selecting on (due to the lack of a join)

Comment: can you please add _filterEmailConditionCallback code here.  i will provide soluction

Comment: @Rama _filterEmailConditionCallback was already included in above source

Comment: okey i will check and provide the solution :)